# Como inserir caractere de emoji num campo TEXT do MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, codificação-de-caracteres

Eu tenho um editor de texto. Nesse editor de texto, salvo as informações numa tabela, usando uma coluna do tipo `MEDIUMTEXT`.

Quando tentei inserir um emoji, apareceu o seguinte erro:

> Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x83\xF0\x9F...' for column 'texto' at row 1

O collation da minha tabela é `utf8_unicode_ci`.

Há algum problema em relação à codificação? 
Como posso corrigir isso?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Utilize o charset "utf8mb4". Ela dará suporte para armazenar a representação da string do emoji e outras coisas que um charset comum não suporta. Pode usar um alter semelhante a esse se precisar alterar o charset do banco todo:

```
ALTER DATABASE
    exemplo
    CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
    COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Outro exemplo aplicando o charset em uma coluna específica:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela MODIFY coluna VARCHAR(250) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```